# why is String.split("£", 2) not working?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a text file with 1000 lines in the following format:

```
19 x 75 Bullnose Architrave/Skirting £1.02
```

I am writing a method that reads the file line by line in  - This works OK.

I then want to split each string using the "£" as a deliminater & write it out to 
an `ArrayList<String>` in the following format:

```
19 x 75 Bullnose Architrave/Skirting, Metre, 1.02
```

This is how I have approached it (`productList` is the `ArrayList`, declared/instantiated outside the try block):

```
try{
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
    String inputLine = br.readLine();
    String delim = "£";

    while (inputLine != null){
        String[]halved = inputLine.split(delim, 2);
        String lineOut = halved[0] + ", Metre, " + halved[1];//Array out of bounds
        productList.add(lineOut);

        inputLine = br.readLine();
    }
}
```

The String is not splitting and I keep getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I'm not very familiar with regex. I've also tried using the old `StringTokenizer` but get the same result.

Is there an issue with `£` as a delim or is it something else? I did wonder if it is something to do with the second token not being read as a `String`?

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: what does `System.out.println(inputLine.indexOf(delim));` print, when you have it as the first operation your loop?

Comment: There are some possible reason: 1) Encoding of the source file and the encoding used in the compilation command does not match 2) The encoding of the reader is not specified correctly. Most likely 2) from your code.

Comment: print inputLine before splitting it and check the content.

Comment: If it is (1) you can use `String delim = "\u00A3"` to make sure it's the right string regardless of the encoding of the `.java` file.

Comment: Can you make sure that each line contains `£`? Also, as a suggestion, you can use a small test file, with one line only, and print everything to see where the problem is.

Comment: @assylias input line print out returns as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some of the possible causes:

- The encoding of the file doesn't match the encoding that you are using to read it, and the "pound" character in the file is getting "mangled" into something else.
- The file and your source code are using different pound-like characters.  For instance, Unicode has two code points that look like a "pound sign" - the Pound Sterling character (00A3) and the Lira character (2084) ... then there is the Roman semuncia character (10192).
- You are trying to compile a UTF-8 encoded source file without tell the compiler that it is UTF-8 encoded.

---

Judging from your comments, this is an encoding mismatch problem; i.e. the "default" encoding being used by Java doesn't match the actual encoding of the file.  There are two ways to address this:

- Change the encoding of the file to match Java's default encoding.  You seem to have tried that and failed.  (And it wouldn't be the way I'd do this ...)
- Change the program to open the file with a specific (non default) encoding; e.g. change

  ```
  new FileReader(aFile)
  ```

  to

  ```
  new FileReader(aFile, encoding)
  ```

  where `encoding` is the name of the file's actual character encoding.  The names of the encodings understood by Java are listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html), but my guess is that it is "ISO-8859-1" (aka Latin-1).

Comment: @jlordo System.out.println(inputLine.indexOf(delim)); returns -1.

Comment: @nhahtdh - using Notepad ++ , i have tried saving the file formatted as UTF 8 endof/endon etc...to no avail!

Comment: 19 x 50 Bullnose Architrave ð.69

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a case of encoding mismatch. To check for this,

- Print `delim.length` and make sure it is `1`.
- Print `inputLine.length` and make sure it is the right value (`42`).

If one of them is not the expected value then you have to make sure you are using UTF-8 everywhere.

You say `delim.length` is 1, so this is good. On the other hand if `inputLine.length` is 34, this is *very* wrong. For `"19 x 75 Bullnose Architrave/Skirting £1.02"` you should get 42 if all was as expected. If your file was UTF-8 encoded but read as ISO-8859-1 or similar you would have gotten 43.

Now I am a little at a loss. To debug this you could print individually each character of the string and check what is wrong with them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputLine.length; i++)
    System.err.println("debug: " + i + ": " + inputLine.charAt(i) + " (" + inputLine.codePointAt(i) + ")");
```

Comment: `delim.length` will always be 1.

Comment: @assylias Not if the source file is encoded in UTF-8 and the compiler thinks it is ISO-8859-1 (or another single byte charset).

Comment: @assylias This is what *you* see. My point is to check what the *compiler* sees.

Comment: @Kmkaplan index of delim ..-1 length of delim 1 length of inputline 34

Comment: @SimonPage “length of inputline 34”? This is very wrong. See my edit for some debugging tracks.

Answer (score -1):

Many thanks for all your replies.

Specifying the encoding within the read & saving the original text file as UTF -8 has worked.

However, the experience has taught me that delimiting text using "£" or indeed other characters that may have multiple representations in different encodings is a poor strategy.

I have decided to take a different approach:

1) Find the last space in the input string & replace it with "xxx" or similar.

2) Split this using the delimiter "xxx." which should split the strings & rip out the "£".

3) Carry on..

Comment: Instead of the horrible hack of replacing a space with a marker to split on, why not some variant of: `int split_idx = inputLine.lastIndexOf(" "); if (split_idx >= 0) lineOut = inputLine.substring(0, split_idx) + ", Metre," + inputLine.substring(split_idx);`